# PHP parse POST data

Tags: php

As you know PHP replaces dots and spaces from `$_POST` and `$_GET` keys with _.

Example:

```
<input name="foo bar" />
```

becomes `$_POST['foo_bar']` after sent to server instead of `$_POST['foo bar']`.

Could you point me to a script that can handle this correctly even with arrays with depth `(name="fo.o[bar][12][]")`? Replacing . before sending the form with a character(s) is not an option since post is coming from an external non editable source.

Solution should handle raw post data.

Comment: why do you go through all the trouble?

Comment: Just don't use spaces and dots ... HTML can be manipulated even the source is external

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I made some code for this](https://gist.github.com/MattiJarvinen/5983909) a bit hacky and could be more effective but works.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an algorithmic solution to your problem, but it will solve your problem.

There are libraries out there designed to make processing request data more simple.  One of them is the Request class from Symfony:
http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

It wraps ParameterBag, so it is very easy to get data:
http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html

Basic usage is:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
echo $request->get('parameter_name');
```

It handles multi-dimensional parameters as well.

You can read more about it at:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html